# Custom Buffer Rendering in NextLevel's slow motion mode

Tags: swift, video-recording, slowmotion, nextlevel

There's a NextLevel video capture library in Swift called "NextLevel".

According to NextLevel's description, https://github.com/NextLevel/NextLevel,

it supports Custom Buffer Rendering.

But I'd like to know it's supported for slow motion mode. So far, I was trying to use it without luck. It worked for normal recording, but not for slow motion.

Am I missing something?

My goal is adding a logo/watermark to the recorded video.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you found anything about this watermark?